# React updating a components state from another component causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have what is basically a form wizard with multiple steps. The wizard is divided into two parts: labels and contents. When a content component changes its internal state, from say `incomplete` to `error` or something, I want the wizard to update the label. The issue I am running into is grabbing the state from the `contents` component, trying to save that in the `wizard` component as a state so I can update the `labels` is causing an infinite loop.

While I understand the problem I don't really know how to solve it. This is a *very* minimal example and my real components use some advanced features like `cloneElement` to pass props to user components without them having to worry about setting 10 different props. So far this has worked flawlessly until now.

So I understand that each time I update my main components state, it's going to re-render the children, which will call the same set state function forever. What can I do instead?

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

// This component containsLabel children
interface LabelState {
  error: boolean;
}
interface LabelGroupProps {
  states: LabelState[],
}
const LabelGroup = (props: LabelGroupProps) => {
  return (<div>I am Comp A</div>)
}

// This component contains Component children
interface ContentState {
  error: boolean;
}
interface ContentGroupProps {
  getStates: (state: ContentState, index: number) => void
}
const ContentGroup = (props: ContentGroupProps) => {
  // Indicate that step 2 has an error
  props.getStates({
    error: true
  }, 2)
  return (<div>I am Comp B</div>)
}

// This is the main wizard that contains both above components
// When the state of the a content component changes, the labels must be updated.
const App = () => {
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState<LabelState[]>([]);

  const getStates = (state: ContentState, index: number) => {
    // This causes an infinite loop
    // The intention is to save this state and then update the labels
    const temp = [];
    temp[index] = state;
    setStates(prev => [...prev, ...temp])
  }

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <LabelGroup states={states}/>
      <ContentGroup getStates={getStates}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-1ypi6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by updating state every time `ContentGroup` renders. Any time there is a change in props or state, a component will automatically re-render. Then the component updates state again, then we render again, and so on. We can fix that.

What is your intention with calling `getStates`? You say:

```js
// Indicate that step 2 has an error
```

An error could be in response to some event. For example, the user has clicked 'submit' on a form and you have a custom validation error. That might look like this:

```js
const ContentGroup = (props: ContentGroupProps) => {
  // Indicate that step 2 has an error
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const someErrorCondition = /* snip */;
        props.getStates({
          error: someErrorCondition
        }, 2);
      }}
    >
      {/* snip */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

This would not cause an infinite loop in the render because a change in state does not cause `ContentGroup` to call the `onSubmit` handler again.

Sometimes you want to perform initialization and cleanup as a component mounts and unmounts:

```js
const ContentGroup = (props: ContentGroupProps) => {
  // Indicate that step 2 has an error
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.getStates({
      error: true
    }, 2);
    return function cleanup() {
      props.getStates({
        error: false
      }, 2);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* snip */
      }}
    >
      {/* snip */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

This does not cause an infinite loop because `getStates` will only be called twice: when the component mounts and right before the component unmounts.

Please treat this as pseudo-code because there are more details to leveraging hooks. Here's the documentation for `useEffect`, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect The example code I posted won't pass many linters because it does not declare `getStates` as part of the hook's dependency array. In this one case, it's actually fine because we're only going to run the effect once. Further changes to `getStates` will be ignored. Here are more details about the dependency array of a hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Comment: Hm I guess you were right, my own simple test of randomly calling `getStates` is silly because it's just happening on every render, not on an actual hook or call or anything.. duh.. Thank you